# Postman always return 404

Tags: php, apache, postman

I have a lot of projects on my local Apache. Everything is set correctly in `httpd.conf` and every project can be launched in the browser as `project-name.localhost`.

Problem is if I want to test it over postman. It always returns 404. Every page where is not any authorisation finished by the same way. All I do is copy the URL from browser, paste it to postman, choose GET method and submit it.

Is in postman any settings which I have to do before testing?

Comment: Why do you downvote instead comment what is wrong?

Comment: It's not me :) More info pls. What projects, how usually do you test it?

Comment: Projects are not important, it is just context. Problem is, that simple url on localhost virtual host some-url.localhost which works in browser in postman return 404 error. Tha is mean, that postman do not work on localhost? Or what is neccessary to do for working on localhost?

Comment: If you're using PhpStorm, you can try to use "Test RESTfull web service" util. It might work for sure :) As for Postman, it's really strange. I guess, at first, you can check http requests in chrome dev toolbar..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, for some reason postman didn't like how I configured apache2 domain aliasing on my machine... but of course it works perfectly fine on my co-workers.

I switched the uri in postman to bypass the vhost.conf / sites.conf

from: http://my-project.laravel5.localhost:port/foo/bar
to: http://localhost:port/laravel/5/my-project/public/foo/bar

- I'm hosting laravel in ~/Sites/laravel/5/my-project/ - so my uri reference starts at the sub directory laravel.
- If you are hosting apache2 on :80 you don't need to specify the port here, but if you're hosting on :8080 you would have to specify localhost:8080/ect... While not a valid solution, I hope this helps.